# Tensorboard debugger graph disappears, only queue left, why?

Tags: python, tensorflow, debugging, tensorboard

I am trying to use the tensorboard debugger to debug my application. I see how the graph gets slowly build, but when the training starts I only see the queue nodes on the CPU and the rest of the graph and the whole GPU section is not visible anymore. It is easiest to explain with a few pictures.

Before I run the first session.run(var.assign(data)) to initialize data:
[image]
[image]
Then I step trough the initialization of the vars:
[image]
and at the end when I start the training with sess.run(training_op):
[image]
**Why do I only see the FIFO queue in the end and not the whole graph?**

It looks like the GPU is getting cut out from the debugging process, but I'm not sure why, because for sure it is getting used, because I have written custom ops, where when I print I get output, but this is a cumbersome way to debug.

I can't post a MVC because the codebase is huge and convoluted, but the principle is:

1. FIFO queues

   - `q = tf.FIFOQueue(queue_size, [tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.int32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32])`
2. graph build up

   - `def make_var(self, name, shape, initializer=None, regularizer=None, trainable=True):
     return tf.get_variable(name, shape, initializer=initializer, regularizer=regularizer, trainable=trainable)`
3. variables initialization

   - `session.run(var.assign(data))`
4. 2nd thread started to feed the queues

   - `t = threading.Thread(target=load_and_enqueue, args=(sess, self.net, data_layer, coord_train, iters_train))`
5. training loop

   - point 5 and 6 are both shown here:

formatting dummy text

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    coord_train.run = True
    coord_val.run = True
    t = threading.Thread(target=load_and_enqueue, args=(sess, self.net, data_layer, coord_train, iters_train))
    t.start()
    t_val = threading.Thread(target=load_and_enqueue_val, args=(sess, self.net, data_layer, coord_val, iters_val))
    print("Epoch: %d / %d" % (epoch, epochs))
    for iter_train in range(iters_train):

        timer.tic()
        loss_summary, loss_cls_summary, loss_vertex_summary, loss_pose_summary, loss_regu_summary, loss_value, loss_cls_value, loss_vertex_value, loss_pose_value, loss_regu_value, lr, _ \
            = sess.run([loss_op, loss_cls_op, loss_vertex_op, loss_pose_op, loss_regu_op, loss, loss_cls, loss_vertex, loss_pose, loss_regu, learning_rate, train_op])
```

Let me know if I can provide more information and what kind would be useful to debug this problem.